# Unity3D + Kinect V2 | How to detect people when they are standing side to device

Tags: unity, kinect, body

I can't detect people when they are standing/walking **side to device**.

I have used Miscrosoft's library for Unity3D to kinect and it works perfect when somebody stands direct front to Kinect device - the problem is my app should track people when they are walking side to device (Like - Kinect is standing in shop exhibition and people are walking on the street).

Kinect doesn't see anybody until that person turn (and show front of his body) to device.